# Are answers recommending non-TeX solutions welcome?

Tags: discussion, answers, scope

I sometimes recommend non-TeX solutions to questions here.  For example, `pdftk`, `pdfcrop`, and `imagemagick` are tools I've recommended.  My standard has been that I'll only recommend the non-TeX tool if I think it is better suited to the job.

Sometimes though I wonder if my recommendations are welcome in a group specifically focused on TeX.  There are many shades of gray.  For example, I doubt anyone here wants to know how to achieve an effect in MSWord.  However, if someone tags their question with `tikz`, is it appropriate to give an answer using `asymptote`?  Does it change your opinion if the `asymptote` solution is easier than the `tikz` solution? (I know that's subjective.)

Comment: I use Google Sketchup occasionally for 3D constructions as the user interface is far easier than coding something. Here are three such suggestive answers: [Best Drawing software for engineering/scientific illustrations with LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158456/5764); [What packages or tools best support any 3D line, plane, surface intersections?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80198/5764); [Draw an aircraft with Tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114837/5764)

Comment: I use Python all the time to automate database-y TeX files. I've used it in at least one answer on this site: [Grabbing data from website and use it in LaTeX document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142933/17423)

Comment: Related discussions mostly focused on graphics questions, but also applicable in general: [Downvoting answers exploiting different approaches with respect to the initial question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3408) and [Best practise for answers which are for the community, not the OP ("tikz answer to pstricks question")](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3452)

Comment: There's always a chance the question is an example of [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), in which case, alternative solutions could be much better than ones satisfying the OP's constraints. And the [400+ hits for Pandoc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=pandoc) indicate alternative markup languages could be useful at times.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Solutions using alternative tools which fall within the 'TeX sphere' are entirely appropriate and have always been welcome. Obvious examples are that plain or ConTeXt solutions to LaTeX problems are often possible, or that picture mode, MetaPost, ... answers to TikZ question are often illustrative. For that to work, of course, there needs to be some care in how such answers are posted. In particular, they ideally will 'flag up' the difference of method and be written in a 'positive' way ('This is how I would achieve the effect using tool X ....').

Comment: I wonder though if languages like Python/Perl/Lua fall within the 'TeX sphere', but I suppose that's exactly what you mean by taking some care in how the answers are posted :)

Comment: @SeanAllred I've occasionally included a perl script in my answer here.  So far no one has complained to me about this.  I think for some of us how may be more familiar with various command line tools such answers can be extremely useful:  particularly if we don't necessarily know how to implement (or understand how the implementation works) in TeX and friends.